# ThinReports: Output in firefox doesn't have spaces in between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, report

I'm trying to check the output of ThinReports PDF. I found out that in firefox (v.26), words doesn't have spaces in between (please see here >> http://postimg.org/image/p7bogl5vl/ <<) unlike in Chrome (v.31), it does have spaces (please see here >> http://postimg.org/image/xwjwrz6k7/ <<).

I can still expound the codes on how I generate the PDF, if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the 0.7.7. In 0.7.6 or less, the ThinReports replaces all white spaces in the string with no-break space (NBSP), so it might be the cause.